# views exposed filter does not redirect to itself

Tags: views

I came across to issue with exposed filter in my view. In a view's preview everything works fine. But on the page, after clicking apply button, the site redirects to front page, with get parameters in URL. What is wrong with this? I did everything in a UI and I didn't work with code. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using https://www.drupal.org/project/mefibs ?

Comment: No. I am using basic exposed form, but I've already tried also better exposed filters.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the views cache? (admin/structure/views/settings/advanced)

Comment: Yes, I did many times.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the "Advanced" pane on the View config page: There is "Link display" where you can define custom URL for the view - it's something like a "base path" for the view and the exposed filter values will be added to it, e.g.: if you define `my-view-path` than the filtered view has the path `my-view-path-?filter_1=true&filter_2=false&filter_3=&filter_4=0`.

Hint: If you have created a panel pane you have to set "Link to view" to `yes` in "Pane settings" to make use of path/URL defined in "Link display".

Comment: I haven't such a option in views advanced config page. There's just configuration for view's cache.

Comment: It should look like here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_DKW9rwffcQNEl2Y2Y0c19WczA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, although perhaps not in exactly the same configuration as that described in the question.

I have a Views Page with an exposed block. The exposed block works when placed on the page, but not when I place it in a panel. The block would use the path of the current page rather than redirecting to the Views page.

The solution was do disable the "Inherit Current Path" option in the block settings in my panel.